# Isomorphism implies direct sum of Kernel and Image

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, transformation

> If  $f: U \rightarrow V$ and $g: V \rightarrow W$ are linear transformations between  vector spaces over a field $K$ such that $ g \circ f$ is an isomorphism, then $V = \operatorname{Im}f \oplus \operatorname{Ker} g$.

I tried this way: since $g\circ f\colon U\to W$ is an isomorphism, I can set $h\colon W\to U$ to be its inverse; then I have  $V$ back to $V$ with $\varphi=f\circ h\circ g$. If $v\in V$, so $v=\varphi(v)+(v-\varphi(v))$,  then $V = \operatorname{Im} f \oplus \operatorname{Ker} g$.

Is it correct? Does there exist a direct or more simple proof of this?

Some help please, thanks for your time.

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma. It is in general true that if an isomorphism factors as $r\circ s$ then $r$ is a retract and $s$ is a section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is correct. Indeed $\varphi(v)=f(h(g(v)))\in\operatorname{Im}f$. Moreover,
$$
g(v-\varphi(v))=g(v)-(g\circ f\circ h\circ g)(v)=g(v)-g(v)=0
$$
since $g\circ f\circ h$ is the identity.

This proves that $V=\operatorname{Im}f+\operatorname{Ker}g$, but you also need to show that
$$
\operatorname{Im}f\cap\operatorname{Ker}g=\{0\}
$$
You should be able to do it.

Comment: How do you know that if $h \circ (g \circ f)=I_d$ implies $g \circ (f \circ h)=I_d$?

Comment: @AnaS.H. I'm not using that. Anyway, since $g\circ f$ is an isomorphism, if $h$ is its left inverse, it is also its right inverse.